# Replacing all numbers (and only numbers) inside <sup> tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm having many problems to get a regex working to make some replaces all across a string.

I need to find and replace all the numbers (and only the numbers) inside `<sup>` tags wrapping each one of them within three curly braces (ie. `{{{1}}}`). They can come in many written ways like:

```
<sup>1</sup>
<sup>1, 2</sup>
<sup>1, 2, 3</sup>
<sup>1, 2, 3\-4</sup>
<sup>1, 2, 3- 4</sup>
```

The expected result for these examples should be something like:

```
<sup>{{{1}}}</sup>
<sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}</sup>
<sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}}</sup>
<sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}}\-{{{4}}}</sup>
<sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}}- {{{4}}}</sup>
```

Sadly, I've tried tons of stuff but couldn't get nothing to work. One example:

```
#<sup>([^<\d]*)(\d+)([^<]*)</sup>#
```

It works with the `<sup>123</sup>` example and will match the first number into the other examples, but it won't get anything after the first one.

Any help and/or clue will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good, have you tried anything specific yet?

Comment: Sadly, I've tried tons of stuff but couldn't get nothing to work. One example: `#<sup>([^<\d]*)(\d+)([^<]*)</sup>#` will work with the `<sup>123</sup>` example and will match the first number into the other examples, but it won't get anything after the first one.

Comment: One question then: can there be nested `sup` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there can be no nested `<sup>` tags, it seems you can use a regex for this task.

The easiest approach is to match all `<sup>` tags (with a mere `'~<sup>[^<]*</sup>~'`) and replace all digit chunks with what you need inside the callback (using a very simple `'~\d+~'` regex):

```
$s = '<sup>1, 2, 3- 124</sup>';
echo preg_replace_callback('~<sup>[^<]*</sup>~', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\d+~', '{{{$0}}}', $m[0]);
}, $s);
// => <sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}}- {{{124}}}</sup>
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Sy1LPu)

If you prefer a 1-regex approach to be used with `preg_replace`, use a `\G` based regex:

```
~(?:\G(?!\A)[^\d<]*|<sup>[^\d<]*)\K\d+~
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2U4wAM/3) and [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/KPZdNp):

```
$s = '<sup>1, 2, 3- 124</sup> 2345';
echo preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)[^\d<]*|<sup>[^\d<]*)\K\d+~', '{{{$0}}}', $s);
// => <sup>{{{1}}}, {{{2}}}, {{{3}}}- {{{124}}}</sup> 2345
```

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)[^\d<]*|<sup>[^\d<]*)` - a custom boundary, either of the two:

  - `\G(?!\A)[^\d<]*`  - the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) and then  0+ chars other than `<` and digits
  - `|` - or
  - `<sup>[^\d<]*` - `<sup>` and 0+ chars other than `<` and digits
- `\K` - operator omitting the whole text matched so far in the current iteration
- `\d+` - 1+ digits

Comment: Sorry for a ton of edits, just made sure the `\D` is `[^\d<]` in order to stay withing the tag.

Comment: You rock, Wiktor! I owe you a [coffee|beer]. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: You meant `(coffee|beer)` :). Yes, coffee is better, I do not drink alcohol.

Comment: You see? That's why I didn't make it works, I simply sucks on regex. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
function sanitizeString($string) {

// matriz de entrada
$what = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

// matriz de saída
$by = array('{{0}}','{{1}}','{{2}}','{{3}}','{{4}}','{{5}}','{{6}}','{{7}}','{{8}}','{{9}}');

// devolver a string
return str_replace($what, $by, $string);
}

echo sanitizeString("hoje é dia 1 testando o 2");
```

This is the simplest way without using regex.

Comment: This way, you 1) do not make sure the replacement happens only inside `<sup>` tags, and 2) `123` will turn into `{{1}}{{2}}{{3}}` instead of `{{123}}`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I really did not think of that.